# rails and engineyard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, engineyard

I am running a rails application on engine yard. Users can upload images that are then returned later. The issue is that we currently have 2 instances running. Just wondering what the best course of action is since currently when an image is uploaded it does not get added to both file systems, only to 1. Is it ok to just hit terminate on the top instance or is there a better solution.

[image: screnshot]

Comment: Store your uploads on amazon s3 (or other) instead of on the file system of yor rails application

Comment: Many thanks, can you provide any info or links on how this can be achieved, I am currently using CarrierWave for the upload. Is there any reason I shouldnt terminate the top instance for now to stop this issue occurring.

Comment: I am not familiar with engine yard infrastructure, but running a single instance seems like a good idea in the short term

Comment: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave scroll down to the s3 section, it uses the fog gem https://github.com/fog/fog/wiki